# JSON nested object to HTML Nested Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm having trouble getting this to nest the correct way. It needs to nest just like the object is nested. A td for the key, and new td / table for objects or if values, it shows a table with the name / value.

Any direction would help.

The json string is this:

```
{
"accounts": {
    "demo": {
        "Name": "Your Medical Clinic",
        "groupid": "demo",
        "CallerID": "8664738160",
        "CallerID_err": "OK",
        "TransferPhone": "1-931-555-1212",
        "TransferPhone_err": "INVALID LENGTH",
        "TimeZone": "EST",
        "EMRSoftware": "Greenway",
        "merlin": 1,
        "prm": 1,
        "CallDaysOut": 2,
        "EmailDaysOut": 5,
        "enablevoice": 1,
        "enabletext": 1,
        "enablemail": 1,
        "Exclude": "12 Months,12-17 Years,18+ Years,2 Months,",
        "emailBtnConfirm": 1,
        "emailBtnReschedule": 1,
        "emailBtnCancel": 1,
        "enablenoshow": 1,
        "enablecollection": 0,
        "enablerecall": 1,
        "enableapptalert": 1,
        "AppendCallerID": "Confirm,Cancel,Resched,AnsMach",
        "EmailReport": "kevin@relatient.net,john@relatient.net,hello@gim.com",
        "EmailReport_err": "OK",
        "SurveyReport": "chris@relatient.net",
        "SurveyReport_err": "OK",
        "HMReport": "john@relatient.net,kevin@relatient.net",
        "HMReport_err": "OK",
        "ApptReminders": {
            "cronCalls": {
                "cronCalls_570": {
                    "StartHour": 18,
                    "StartQtrHour": 0,
                    "StartTime_local": "7:00 PM EST",
                    "EndHour": 19,
                    "EndQtrHour": 0,
                    "EndTime_local": "8:00 PM EST",
                    "CallDays": "MoTuWeThFr"
                }
            },
            "cronEmail": {
                "cronEmail_110": {
                    "hour": 18,
                    "qtrhour": 99,
                    "StartTime_local": "INVALID EST",
                    "ApptTimeMath": "",
                    "EmailDays": "MoTuWeThFr"
                }
            },
            "cronSMS": {
                "cronSMS_82": {
                    "hour": 7,
                    "qtrhour": 0,
                    "StartTime_local": "8:00 AM EST",
                    "DaysOut": 0,
                    "cronargid": 1,
                    "cronargid_type": "frombulk",
                    "ApptTimeMath": "",
                    "WorkDays": "MoTuWeThFr",
                    "SendOnDays": "TuWeThFr",
                    "cronSMS_err": "OK"
                }
            }
        },
        "HealthMaint": {
            "cronHMCalls": {
                "cronHMCalls_2": {
                    "StartHour": 12,
                    "StartQtrHour": 0,
                    "StartTime_local": "1:00 PM EST",
                    "EndHour": 16,
                    "EndQtrHour": 0,
                    "EndTime_local": "5:00 PM EST",
                    "ActiveDays": "MoTuWeFrSa"
                }
            },
            "cronHMEmail": {
                "cronHMEmail_1": {
                    "hour": 3,
                    "qtrhour": 3,
                    "StartTime_local": "4:45 AM EST",
                    "ActiveDays": "ThFrSa"
                }
            },
            "cronHMSMS": {
                "cronHMSMS_1": {
                    "hour": 2,
                    "qtrhour": 2,
                    "StartTime_local": "3:30 AM EST",
                    "ActiveDays": "SuTuThSa"
                }
            }
        },
        "MDPay": {
            "cronMDPayCalls": {
                "cronMDPayCalls_2": {
                    "hour": 15,
                    "qtrhour": 3,
                    "StartTime_local": "4:45 PM EST",
                    "ActiveDays": "MoWeFr"
                }
            },
            "cronMDPayEmail": {
                "cronMDPayEmail_2": {
                    "hour": 13,
                    "qtrhour": 1,
                    "StartTime_local": "2:15 PM EST",
                    "ActiveDays": "MoFr"
                }
            },
            "cronMDPaySMS": {
                "cronMDPaySMS_2": {
                    "hour": 15,
                    "qtrhour": 1,
                    "StartTime_local": "4:15 PM EST",
                    "ActiveDays": "Su"
                }
            }
        },
        "NoShow": {
            "cronNoShowCalls": { }
        },
        "Recall": {
            "cronRecallCalls": {
                "cronRecallCalls_4": {
                    "Hour": 11,
                    "QtrHour": 0,
                    "StartTime_local": "12:00 PM EST",
                    "ActiveDays": "MoTuWeThFr"
                }
            }
        },
        "cronEmailReports": {
            "cronEmailReport_155": {
                "hour": 20,
                "qtrhour": 1,
                "StartTime_local": "9:15 PM EST",
                "DaysOut": 4,
                "csv": 1,
                "reportargid": 3,
                "reportargid_type": "calltime",
                "WorkDays": "SuMoTuThFrSa",
                "SendOnDays": "MoTuWeThFr"
            }
        },
        "CallCntNotStatus99": 3680,
        "crontab": { },
        "IncomingFiles": {
            "file_1": "payments.json",
            "file_1_changed": "2015-04-08 10:44",
            "file_1_lines": 222,
            "file_2": "recall.csv",
            "file_2_changed": "2014-04-17 08:58",
            "file_2_lines": 0,
            "file_3": "elerts.txt",
            "file_3_changed": "2014-12-11 14:14",
            "file_3_lines": 21,
            "file_4": "noshow.csv",
            "file_4_changed": "2014-04-17 08:44",
            "file_4_lines": 0,
            "file_5": "daily.txt",
            "file_5_changed": "2014-10-29 12:50",
            "file_5_lines": 188,
            "file_6": "bulk.csv",
            "file_6_changed": "2014-10-20 14:41",
            "file_6_lines": 1
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code i'm using to create an HTML table:

```js
// Settings :: Configuration
var jsontext = '{ "accounts" : { "demo": { "Name": "Your Medical Clinic", "groupid": "demo", "CallerID": "8664738160", "CallerID_err": "OK", "TransferPhone": "1-931-555-1212", "TransferPhone_err": "INVALID LENGTH", "TimeZone": "EST", "EMRSoftware": "Greenway", "merlin": 1, "prm": 1, "CallDaysOut": 2, "EmailDaysOut": 5, "enablevoice": 1, "enabletext": 1, "enablemail": 1, "Exclude": "12 Months,12-17 Years,18+ Years,2 Months,", "emailBtnConfirm": 1, "emailBtnReschedule": 1, "emailBtnCancel": 1, "enablenoshow": 1, "enablecollection": 0, "enablerecall": 1, "enableapptalert": 1, "AppendCallerID": "Confirm,Cancel,Resched,AnsMach", "EmailReport": "kevin@relatient.net,john@relatient.net,hello@gim.com", "EmailReport_err": "OK", "SurveyReport": "chris@relatient.net", "SurveyReport_err": "OK", "HMReport": "john@relatient.net,kevin@relatient.net", "HMReport_err": "OK", "ApptReminders" : { "cronCalls": { "cronCalls_570": { "StartHour": 18, "StartQtrHour": 0, "StartTime_local": "7:00 PM EST", "EndHour": 19, "EndQtrHour": 0, "EndTime_local": "8:00 PM EST", "CallDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } }, "cronEmail": { "cronEmail_110": { "hour": 18, "qtrhour": 99, "StartTime_local": "INVALID EST", "ApptTimeMath": "", "EmailDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } }, "cronSMS": { "cronSMS_82": { "hour": 7, "qtrhour": 0, "StartTime_local": "8:00 AM EST", "DaysOut": 0, "cronargid": 1, "cronargid_type": "frombulk", "ApptTimeMath": "", "WorkDays": "MoTuWeThFr", "SendOnDays": "TuWeThFr", "cronSMS_err": "OK" } } }, "HealthMaint" : { "cronHMCalls": { "cronHMCalls_2": { "StartHour": 12, "StartQtrHour": 0, "StartTime_local": "1:00 PM EST", "EndHour": 16, "EndQtrHour": 0, "EndTime_local": "5:00 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoTuWeFrSa" } }, "cronHMEmail": { "cronHMEmail_1": { "hour": 3, "qtrhour": 3, "StartTime_local": "4:45 AM EST", "ActiveDays": "ThFrSa" } }, "cronHMSMS": { "cronHMSMS_1": { "hour": 2, "qtrhour": 2, "StartTime_local": "3:30 AM EST", "ActiveDays": "SuTuThSa" } } }, "MDPay" : { "cronMDPayCalls": { "cronMDPayCalls_2": { "hour": 15, "qtrhour": 3, "StartTime_local": "4:45 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoWeFr" } }, "cronMDPayEmail": { "cronMDPayEmail_2": { "hour": 13, "qtrhour": 1, "StartTime_local": "2:15 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoFr" } }, "cronMDPaySMS": { "cronMDPaySMS_2": { "hour": 15, "qtrhour": 1, "StartTime_local": "4:15 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "Su" } } }, "NoShow" : { "cronNoShowCalls": { } }, "Recall" : { "cronRecallCalls": { "cronRecallCalls_4": { "Hour": 11, "QtrHour": 0, "StartTime_local": "12:00 PM EST", "ActiveDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } } }, "cronEmailReports": { "cronEmailReport_155": { "hour": 20, "qtrhour": 1, "StartTime_local": "9:15 PM EST", "DaysOut": 4, "csv": 1, "reportargid": 3, "reportargid_type": "calltime", "WorkDays": "SuMoTuThFrSa", "SendOnDays": "MoTuWeThFr" } }, "CallCntNotStatus99": 3680, "crontab": { }, "IncomingFiles": { "file_1": "payments.json", "file_1_changed": "2015-04-08 10:44", "file_1_lines": 222, "file_2": "recall.csv", "file_2_changed": "2014-04-17 08:58", "file_2_lines": 0, "file_3": "elerts.txt", "file_3_changed": "2014-12-11 14:14", "file_3_lines": 21, "file_4": "noshow.csv", "file_4_changed": "2014-04-17 08:44", "file_4_lines": 0, "file_5": "daily.txt", "file_5_changed": "2014-10-29 12:50", "file_5_lines": 188, "file_6": "bulk.csv", "file_6_changed": "2014-10-20 14:41", "file_6_lines": 1 } } }}
',
  obj = JSON.parse(jsontext),
  path = '',
  table = $('#configurationTable'),
  parent = '';

console.log(obj);
// if no object available, rerturn false
if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
  console.log('error');
  return false;
}

$.each(obj, lp);

// Build Table
function lp(key, val) {
  var savepath = path;
  path = path ? (path + "-" + key) : key;

  // create table structure
  var struct = path,
    structArr = path.split('-'),
    length = (structArr.length > 2) ? structArr.length - 1 : structArr.length,
    last = '';

  // recursion for children
  if (val !== null && typeof val === "object") {
    for (var v in structArr) {
      if (last != '') {
        last = $('table.' + structArr[v], last);
        if (last.length == 0) {
          console.log(parent);
          parent.append('<b>' + structArr[v] + '</b><table class="' + structArr[v] + '"><tr></tr></table>');
          parent = $('.' + structArr[v], parent);
        } else {

        }
      } else {
        last = $('table.' + structArr[v], table);
        if (last.length == 0) {
          table.append('<b>' + structArr[v] + '</b><table class="' + structArr[v] + '"><tr></tr></table>');
          parent = $('.' + structArr[v], table);
        }
      }
    }

    // Recursion
    $.each(val, lp);
  }
  // Show values per div
  else {
    $(parent).append('<tr><td class="name">' + key + '</td><td class="value">' + val + '</td></tr>');

  }
  path = savepath;
}

$('.jsonConfig').html(table);
```

```html
<h3>Configuration JSON</h3>
<div class="form_panel jsonConfig">
  
  <table id="configurationTable"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: So is it working without nested data ? Also can you please put this in jsfiddle ?

Comment: What console error do you get?

Comment: I'll get a fiddle made. And I'm not really recieving an error. It's just displaying incorrect. It's nesting like this. table{ table{ table{ table{}}}}.

Comment: I need it nesting like this: table{ table{ table{} table{} table{}} table{table{} table{}}}

Comment: @Shadoweye14, they shouldn't need a ;. There all initaited with var jsontext, obj, path, table, parent; Parent has the semicolon.

Comment: @jamadri apologies. I thought you were asking a different thing. Let m get back to you on that.

Comment: @shadoweye14 Your ok, thanks for the response. Can you post a link to that fiddle in the comments? For some odd reason I still can't get the fiddle to work. Thanks again for the help. I've been stressing for hours trying to get this to nest correctly.

Comment: For everyone else, just incase it gets removed again, thanks to shadoweye for fixing the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/25wveof1/

Answer (score 0):

****Incorrect Response Deleted****

Okay so after a while of going though your code, I kind of figured out (I think) why you are going wrong. The reason is because, looking at this [**Pastebin**](http://pastebin.com/Ns22dK0x) on both the conditions where you check the value of the variable `last` to see if there are anymore child tables to be created, you are performing an append. An `.append()` function edits the value of the selector element and adds your chosen text to it. It does not add your chosen text next to (after) your chosen element.

Hence you are getting the table format that is 100% nested instead of a systematic nesting in accordance with your JSON structure. ie `this{ this{ this{ this{ this{} } } } }` and not `this{ this{ this{}  this{} }  this{ this{}  this{}  this{} }  this{ this{} } }` etc. lol xP

I suggest you use something like an [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) function to make sure that at the last child the next table to added after and not appended to the markup.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly how it's displaying. I need it displayed correctly though. If you look at the contents it's nesting it into just table after table. I need it nested like the object though. That's my issue.

Comment: I see. I understood it incorrectly let m get back to you.

Comment: Path variable is used to show the nested objects path. Basically, the path of the key that's looped through.
Last is used to show which table is being created. It basically takes the path and creates a table if there is an object, only if the table element doesn't exist yet.